# @SpringBootTest fails to load application yaml from @ActiveProfiles

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-test

This test fails for not finding vault token while I've disabled vault in `application-test.yml`

```
@DirtiesContext(classMode = AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)
@EmbeddedKafka(brokerProperties = {"listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:19092"})
@ActiveProfiles("test")
class PostIntegrationTest {
...
}
```

I have a file named `application-test.yml` in `src/test/resources`

running test gives this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot create authentication mechanism for TOKEN. This method requires either a Token (spring.cloud.vault.token) or a token file at ~/.vault-token.
    at org.springframework.cloud.vault.config.ClientAuthenticationFactory.tokenAuthentication(ClientAuthenticationFactory.java:425)
    at org.springframework.cloud.vault.config.ClientAuthenticationFactory.createClientAuthentication(ClientAuthenticationFactory.java:148)
    at org.springframework.cloud.vault.config.VaultAutoConfiguration.clientAuthentication(VaultAutoConfiguration.java:232)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
    ... 157 more
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
@DirtiesContext(classMode = AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT, properties = {
        "spring.config.location=classpath:/application-test.yml"
})
@EmbeddedKafka(brokerProperties = {"listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:19092"})
@ActiveProfiles("test")
class PostIntegrationTest {
...
}
```